# anyone can help me how to count the objects using yolov5?

Tags: object, counting, yolov5

I have followed the tutorial in [yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5). When I finished the train and start the test, I would like to count how many objects based on label.
Here, I add this code in file detect.py

```
class_name_count = 'tree'
            l = s[1:s.find(class_name_count)].split()[-1]
            if class_name_count in s:
                print(l,class_name_count)
                cv2.rectangle(im0, (0,0), (1100, 250), -1)
                cv2.putText(im0,1 + class_name_count,(0,200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,(255,255,255),8,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

but the output is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your results to *.txt file and then import them. Just add this line: **--save_txt**

Example:

```
python detect.py --source input/image_1.jpg --weights yolov5x.pt --project infer_yolov5x --save-txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't basically add up a string and a integer variable.
Refer to this link: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2696